# Disable the "double-click to collapse cell group" feature in Mathematica?

Tags: front-end, editing

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to disable the feature of Mathematica whereby if you double click the brackets to the right of a formula + output, it collapses the output.

I want to disable this feature because, sometimes, when I mean to click *once* to copy a formula, sometimes the software misinterprets it as a *double* click and collapses the cell group.

Since I do not actually use the double-click to collapse feature itself, I would rather disable it altogether. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

Setting the option values for `AllowGroupClose` and `AllowReverseGroupClose` to `False` seems to give the desired result:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  {AllowGroupClose -> False, AllowReverseGroupClose -> False}]
```

Replace `EvaluationNotebook[]` with `$FrontEnd` (respectively `$FrontEndSession`) to make the changes apply to global settings for front end (respectively the current session).

Alternatively, you can change these option settings using the Option Inspector from the `Format` menu. The options are located under `Cell Options >> General Properties`.

[image]